# How to keep the session alive or refresh session before expire, in mvc

Tags: .net, session, model-view-controller

Suppose the session timeout is 20. I want to reset the session when the application is idle for 18 minutes, programatically in mvc without postback. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the session alive there are different techniques. One of them is to just make an ajax request and simply hit the web server.

For this you need to call an ajax request in the Javascript function `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(function(){ 
//Call your ajax request here 
 }, 120* 1000);//for 2 min else your time
```